# How to call remote server with basic auth via axios?

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, axios, basic-authentication

I call a remote server with basic auth protected.

```
axios
  .get('http://localhost:9000/posts', {
    auth: {
      username: 'username'
      password: 'password'
    }}
  )
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
```

This doesn't work. If set `auth` with default headers:

```
axios.defaults.auth = {username: 'username', password, 'password'}
```

Or post

```
axios.post('http://localhost:9000/posts', {}, {
  headers: { 'Authorization': + 'Basic ' + btoa('username' + ':' + 'password') }
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Authenticated')
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error on Authentication')
})
```

Neither of them can work.

From its [Request Config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config), the set way is

```
auth: {
    username: 'janedoe',
    password: 's00pers3cret'
  },
```

Where to put it?

---

Tried

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://localhost:9000/posts',
  auth: {
     username: 'username',
     password: 'password'
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
```

Also got error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
axios({
 method: 'post',
 url: 'http://localhost:9000/posts', 
 auth: {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
 }
})
```

should work!
Check out [this](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I tried a way as I posted to the bottom of the question. That doesn't work. Do you mean need to `POST` first, then do other things? But there isn't a post endpoint for basic auth in server side. Just set as a basic auth config.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from the question: do you use token or username/password on server auth? An answer for latter is above. If you use tokens, then try this:

```
const requestOptions = {
    ...options,
    ...{
        headers: {
            authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
        }
    }
};

axios(url, requestOptions)
.then(res => {
    console.log('API call succeeded: ', res); // Read res.data
})
.catch(error => {
    if (error)
        setError(error.response);
    console.log('API call returned an error:', error);
});
```

As for 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - this is a CORS policy error (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) It means that you are making request from different domain than your server. This is not allowed by default in any browser (in order to avoid hacking...). You can't fix this on client. This is should be fixed on server by responding to API calls with additional set of HTTP Headers saying that your domain is allowed (read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Comment: I'm using `username/password` on server auth. I have set CORS config `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on server side. If remove the basic auth check from server, it can access from client with axios. Just want to know the method to use such as we access a web site with basic auth on browser.

Comment: @realworld are you able to check if server gets the response and returns specific HTTP error (like HTTP 500, 401, etc.)?

Comment: It doesn't matter if call server with basic auth from curl.